# Subclassing Graph from the graph_tool package

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, graph-tool

I am attempting to sub-class `Graph` from the `graph_tool` package for some graph analysis in Python (so that I can generate some of my own functions, but still use Graph_Tool's functions as well), and I cannot seem to use `graph_tool`'s graph generator methods.

I start by importing my classes:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
import numpy.random as np
np.seed(42)
```

I've tried various versions of the `__init__` method:

1. Build a graph from scratch.  This works, but I'd prefer not to
   use this, because `graph_tool` has some nice ways to pre-populate
   your graphs (see 2. and 3. below).

   ```
   class myGraph(gt.Graph):
       def __init__(self): 
           super(myGraph, self).__init__()
           self.add_vertex(4)
   ```
2. Use `graph_tool` graph generator methods.  This generates a `gt.Graph` object inside the function.  But when I try to print the object outside the function, I get an error.

   ```
   class myGraph(gt.Graph):
       def __init__(self):
           self = gt.collection.data['celegansneural']
           print self
   g = myGraph()
   print g
   ```

The above code returns (note the first line is the result of `print self` in my `**init** method):

```
     <Graph object, directed, with 297 vertices and 2359 edges at 0x1049d2a50> 
     Traceback (most recent call last): <br>
     File "Graph_Tool.py", line 54, in <module> <br>
        print g <br>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/&#95;_init__.py", line 1683, in &#95;_repr__ <br>
        d = "directed" if self.is_directed() else "undirected" <br>
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/&#95;_init__.py", line 2412, in is_directed <br>
        return self.__graph.get_directed() <br>
    AttributeError: 'myGraph' object has no attribute '_Graph__graph'
```

3. My other approach is to call the parent's `__init__` but then override the object with new data.  When I do this, everything looks fine as long as I stay in my `__init__` method, but once I leave it, my graph is wiped.

   ```
   class myGraph(gt.Graph):
       def __init__(self):
           super(myGraph, self).__init__()         
           self = gt.collection.data['celegansneural']
           print self
   g = myGraph()
   print g
   ```

Which returns the following.  Note the first `print self` returns a populated `Graph` object, whereas the second `print g` returns an empty `myGraph` object

```
<Graph object, directed, with 297 vertices and 2359 edges at 0x11df610d0>
<myGraph object, directed, with 0 vertices and 0 edges at 0x109d14190>
```

I apologize in advance if this is some picky problem of `graph_tool`, library, but I figured that it is more likely my coding error than theirs.

Comment: Assigning to `self` doesn't actually change your object in any way. `self` is an ordinary local variable, and variable assignment never mutates objects like that. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thank you.   That makes sense why 3. isn't working.  I am reassigning the local variable "self" within the method to the object, but since __init__ doesn't return "self", I really haven't modified the object that gets returned from the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem a bit confused about how assignment works in python. But I suppose the correct way to achieve what you want is to call the parent's constructors with the appropriate arguments:

```
class myGraph(gt.Graph):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myGraph, self).__init__(gt.collection.data['celegansneural'])
g = myGraph()
print(g)
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I didn't notice that `Graph.__init__` accepts a graph object to initialize it.  By passing in `gt.collection.data['celegansneural']` to the parents constructor in `myGraph` init, we achieve the effect of creating a `myGraph` that _is_ _a_ `Graph`, and is pre-populated with one of graph-tool's built-in graph generator methods.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should generally prefer composition over inheritance -- unless you want to customize the behavior of the graph class *itself*, you don't need to subclass `gt.Graph`, just have one as a member of your own class. Then you can add your own methods to your class, and use the graph's methods when you need to:

```
class MyGraph(object):
    def __init__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph

    def do_stuff(self):
        # do stuff with self.graph

# Usage:
my_graph = MyGraph(graph=gt.collection.whatever())
my_graph.do_stuff()
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I did uncheck "answer" to change it to Tiago's since his answer achieves the actual intent of inheritance.  I get what you're saying about composition, but in this case, `myGraph` _is_ _a_ `Graph` (not `myGraph` _has_ _a_ `Graph`) so composition doesn't fit exactly.  Still thank you for your answer.