# Sub-classing Graph, Vertex and Edge in python graph-tool at the same time

Tags: python, graph-tool

Is it feasible to sub-class, at the same time, the Graph, Vertex and Edge classes in `graph-tool` in order to implement the behaviour of a certain type of graphs, such as social networks?
More specifically, I would like to have a `class CollaborationNetwork(Graph)` that comprises instances of `class Person(Vertex)`, `class Publication(Vertex)`, `class Authored(Edge)`, etc.
I imagine that the Person and Publication vertices are identified by a `property_map`, while the Graph methods are wrapped into likes of `add_authorship(Person, Publication)` that creates an instance of `Authored`.

What I am not sure is if implementing such abstraction based on `graph-tool` with makes sense and, if yes, how to connect `CollaborationNetwork` to the sub-classes of Vertex and Edge.
(I know how only [Subclassing Graph from the graph_tool package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353080/subclassing-graph-from-the-graph-tool-package) can work).

*About the motivation:*
I will be simulating the growth of a social network and will be comparing it with actual data, which is stored as a Neo4j graph.
I like the py2neo [OGM](http://py2neo.org/v3/ogm.html) approach, which represents these Person and Publication data as python objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but I don't see any real advantage of doing so.

Subclassing `Vertex` is easy, but there are several `Edge` classes, depending on wether the graph is directed or filtered. In order to make it work, you would have to wrap the `Graph` methods in your derived class that return `Vertex` or `Edge` objects (or iterators thereof) so that they convert them to your derived `Edge` and `Vertex` objects.

Doing all this only so that the classes have different names seems to me like a waste of effort. But it is not impossible.

A simpler strategy would be to create a separate class (say `CitationGraph`), that does not subclass `Graph`, but instead contains an instance of one. You can then implement convenience functions like `add_person` and `add_publication` that perform your basic operations, while allowing you to access the underlying `Graph` at any point. Doing so will prevent lots of headaches, and even gives you things like `pickle` support basically for free.

Comment: Thanks, Tiago. This fully answers my questions!
I suspected that even if possible, the "Object-Graph Mapping" approach would be an overkill.
With regards to your suggestion about containing a Graph instance, we already have experience doing so and it works quite nicely: [scientometric-graph-tool](https://github.com/nanumyan/scientometric-graph-tool)